# Makefile to gradle conversion for golang application

Tags: go, gradle, makefile

I have a go lang application which exposes a rest API and logs the information to DB. I am trying to convert the make file to gradle build. Is there any default way similar to maven2gradle plugin or the gradle build file should be written manually? I checked the syntactical differences between gradle and make file but still not clear about passing run time arguments to gradle that is similar to

```
run:build
./hello -conf=/apps/content/properties/prop.json -v=0 -logDest="FILE" -log_dir="/var/log/logdir"
```

hello is my executable and others are the runtime arguments. This is my first attempt in migrating make to gradle and I couldnt find any clear documentation. Please help.

Comment: erm, what's wrong with a simple `run.sh` that does that?

Comment: Have java and go projects in my repository and needed a common build mechanism.Chose gradle because of its advantages.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have checked, there is no direct plugin that could do this task. As a workaround, the build execution could be written as seperate tasks in gradle and ordered accordingly. Tasks here would contain setting Go path, installing dependencies and building the application and would be run as command line process in Gradle. Gradle provides support to run command line processes as described in [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html). Hope it helps.